# I need some clarification about action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

What exactly does `action` do in this reference:

```
export function productsReducer(state = initialState, action)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you shared is a syntax for a reducer which taken in two params, initialState and an action.

An action is something that is triggered from your application. If you aare only using redux, it is fired ussing `store.dispatch()` something like

```
store.dispatch({
  type:'UPDATE_SOMETHING',
  payload: metadata
});
```

This fired action is then received by your reducer as the second argument and it will look like below

```
{
  type:'UPDATE_SOMETHING',
  payload: metadata
}
```

Now the reducer can decide to honour this action or ignore it. A typical implementation of a reducer will look like below

```
export function productsReducer(state = initialState, action) {
   switch(action.type) {
      case 'UPDATE_SOMETHING':
          return {...state, metadata: action.payload},
      default: 
          return state;
   }
 
}
```

It is important to add a default case which returns state so that reducers that do not honour the action don't modify their state as the return value of each reducer is used after an action is dispatched.

Note that each action is a plain object with a mandatory type attribute. You can of course extend on it using middleware such as redux-thunk.